# Git pull asks me to write merge message - no commit before pull

Tags: git

I recently noticed that a git pull asked me to write a commit message.
Git gave me the following message:

```
MYCOMPUTER:_myApp kermit$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 21, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 21 (delta 13), reused 21 (delta 13), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (21/21), done.
From https://github.com/Account/project
   6fabcd3..abcde30  myBranch -> origin/myBranch
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 firebase-functions/functions/src/common/one.js       |  2 +-
 firebase-functions/functions/src/common/two.js | 44 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 firebase-functions/functions/src/common/three.js   |  4 ++--
 3 files changed, 47 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
MYCOMPUTER:_myApp ketmit$
```

I did ***NOT*** make any commits before `git pull` which is why I have seen this message before.

Why did git have a problem doing a ***fast-forward*** merge?

There were a few changes (pushes) to origin that needed to be pulled.
Neither of the changes in origin was in any file I had changed locally. I had ***NO*** local changes in the `firebase-functions/` folder.
My local changes was neither staged nor committed.

All worked well after accepting the standard merge message. For the branch '123' GitHub shows:

```
Commits on Sep 01, 2020
@mspiggy Fix comment                                                abcdef0
@mspiggy Fix contact card info                                      abcdef1
@mspiggy Add functions hello, goodbye and yokuso                    abcdef2
----> THIS IS WHERE THE git pull occurs
Kermit   Merge branch '123' of https://github.com/Account/project … abcdef3 
----> The above merge simply consolidates commits 
       abcdef0, abcdef1 and abcdef3 into ONE commit. Nothing else changes. 
       No changes are lost or rewritten. 
       This should have been possible to do with a fast-forward merge.
```

But the question remains - Why did git have a problem doing a ***fast-forward*** merge?

Kind regards /K

Comment: There were local commits that were different from what the remote had. If you had ABC and the remote had ABCDE you would have gotten a fast forward. You can use git log to prove this.

Comment: Yes, that would have been true if there had been any local commits. But in this case there was not. Which is why I am a bit confused. :) /K

Comment: You are not doing what I am telling you to do. Your inner mental picture of the situation doesn't matter; it could be wrong. Use git log and you will see.

Comment: Hi Matt! Thank you for the prompt reply. I did a commit after the pull-merge. 
My git log now shows: 
abcdef4 (HEAD -> 123, origin/123) add updated page
abcdef3 Merge branch '123' of https://github.com/Account/project into 123
abcdef2 Add functions hello, goodbye and yokuso
abcdef1 Fix contact card info
abcdef0 Fix comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did NOT make any commits before git pull ...

It does not matter *who made* these commits.  All that matters is the commit graph.

Suppose, for instance, that the other Git, over at `https://github.com/Account/project`, originally had these commits in the branch named `myBranch`:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- myBranch
```

When your Git ran `git fetch`—remember, `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, usually `git merge`—you got these commits locally, so that your own Git repository now has:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- origin/myBranch
```

If you now create your own name `myBranch` pointing to commit `I` as well, and check that out as your current branch, you get:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- myBranch (HEAD), origin/myBranch
```

Now suppose whoever controls the repository over at `https://github.com/Account/project`—the repo you call `origin`—decides to *shove aside* commit `I` and put in a different commit `J`.  That is, they use `git push --force` so that `origin` now has:

```
          I   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H--J   <-- myBranch
```

If you now run `git fetch`, you will get, in your repository, this:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- myBranch (HEAD)
         \
          J   <-- origin/myBranch
```

(though at this point, if this is precisely what happened, you would also have seen this text from your two commands as run by `git pull`:

```
From https://github.com/Account/project
  +6fabcd3...abcde30  myBranch -> origin/myBranch (forced update)
```

which is not what you saw—still, we could get there in two steps, if they first removed commit `I`, then added commit `J` later).

At this point, running `git merge`—the second step of `git pull`—would create a merge commit between the commit your Git thinks of as "yours", i.e., commit `I` as found by your name `myBranch`, and the one your Git thinks of as "theirs", i.e., commit `J` as found by your name `origin/myBranch`.  This merge commit looks like:

```
...--G--H--I--K   <-- myBranch (HEAD)
         \   /
          --J   <-- origin/myBranch
```

In effect, you will have resurrected commit `I`, which someone (using `git push --force`, probably) tried to get rid of.

Without actual access to all the repositories involved, this particular possibility is just speculation: I can't know precisely what happened.  But the real point here is that I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`.  Run `git fetch` first, and see what you get.  Then, based on what you got from the fetch, and what you have now, decide whether `git merge` is appropriate, or not.

Using `git pull` means you pre-determine whether `git merge` or `git rebase` is appropriate, and dedicate yourself to running `git fetch` followed by this second Git command, regardless of what `git fetch` actually fetches and what state you end up in as a result.  Sometimes—a lot of time, really—that's appropriate and convenient.  It looks like this time, it was not.  The times when it's not are one reason why I tend to avoid `git pull`.

Comment: Thank you! This was a very helful explanation to how git works. Not all was new to me, but the explanation was excellent. :D What I did was make three simple commits to three different files from another machine and push. Then did a git pull. This scenario should not create a merge problem? Usually it does not. This is the first time ever (hundreds of commits in the branch) Kind regards /K